# Is there any way to set specific monitors to windows users?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, nvidia-settings

I got 5 monitors connected at the same pc with 2 different workbench and i need to dissable the monitors in depence of the windows user, the users are not gonna be simultaneus, but i need to turn off the monitors of the other workbench. Is that possible by using software?

[image]

Comment: It should be possible to have different configurations per user that survive logout/reboot. What have you tried already?

Answer (score 2):

Use [DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/) or [Actual Multiple Monitors](https://www.actualtools.com/multiplemonitors/)

Create a display profile for each individual user. This will allow you to select which active monitor(s) in use by that user and save it as a sepeate profile for them.

The software should allow you to switch display profile depending on which user is logged in. If unsure, simply email support and they'll let you know. Most of these purpose built tools have this option.

Haven't considered mentioning [Microsoft Powertoys](https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/microsoft-powertoys/XP89DCGQ3K6VLD?hl=en-US&gl=US), but might be worth double checking if it's capable. I'm not sure it can do what you're after though.